# user profile update via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

hi guys im trying to update user details via ajax but its not updating my users table and just stop executing when possessing... appear here is my code please help if possible

edit_profile.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["la"])){
$firstname = strip_tags(preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['fi']));
    $lastname = strip_tags(preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['la']));
    $age = strip_tags(preg_replace('#[0-9]#', '', $_POST['ag']));
    $gender = strip_tags(preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['g']));

  // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($gender == "" || $firsname == "" || $lastname == "" || $age == ""){
        echo "some account info is empty.";
        exit();
        }else{
      $sql = "UPDATE users SET gender='$gender', age='$age', lastname='$lastname, firstname='$firstname' WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1";


     $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
echo "account_success";
        exit();

    }

    }
?>
```

ajax and js

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function toggleElement(x){
    var x = _(x);
    if(x.style.display == 'block'){
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }else{
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

function restrict(elem){
    var tf = _(elem);
    var rx = new RegExp;
    if(elem == "firstname"){
        rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
    } else if(elem == "lastname"){
        rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
        } 
    tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open( meth, url, true );
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        return true;    
    }
}
function update_profile() {
    var fi = _("firstname").value;
    var la = _("lastname").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
    var ag = _("age").value;
    var status2 = _("status_profile");
    if(fi == "" || la == "" || ag == "" || g == ""){
        status2.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
        status2.style.color = "red";
    }else {
        _("profilebtn").style.display = "none";
        status2.innerHTML = 'processing ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "edit_profile.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != "account_success"){

                    _("profilebtn").style.display = "block";
                } 
            }
        }
        ajax.send("&fi="+fi+"&la="+la+"&g="+g+"&ag="+ag);   
    }
}
</script>
```

the html

```
 <div class="row profile-classic">
<div class="col-md-12 m-t-20">
<form name="updateform" id="updateform" onsubmit="return false;">
<div id="profile_form" class="panel">
 <div class="panel-title line">
 <div class="caption"><i class="fa fa-phone c-gray m-r-10"></i>ACCOUNT</div>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">

 <div class="row">
<div class="control-label c-gray col-md-3">Username:</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $uname; ?>" disabled="disabled">
   </div>
   </div><br />
 <div class="row">
 <div class="control-label c-gray col-md-3">Firstname: *</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status_profile')" class="form-control" id="firstname" contenteditable="true" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
 </div>
  </div><br />
 <div class="row">
  <div class="control-label c-gray col-md-3">Lastname: *</div> 
<div class="col-md-6">
 <input type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status_profile')" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="your lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" >
 </div>
</div><br />

 <div class="row">
 <div class="control-label c-gray col-md-3">Age: *</div> 
<div class="col-md-6">
 <input type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status_profile')" class="form-control" id="age" value="<?php echo $age; ?>">
</div>
 </div><br />
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
<select class="form-control"  onfocus="emptyElement('status_profile')" id="gender" class="form-control">
<option value="<?php echo $gender; ?>"><?php echo $sex; ?></option>
<option value="m">Male</option>
 <option value="f">Female</option>

 </select>
 </div>
<button id="profilebtn" onclick="update_profile()" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Save</button><span id="status_profile"></span>


</div><br />
  </div>
 </div></form>

</div></div>
```

Comment: Where are you initializing your MySQL connection?

Comment: Not directly related to your problem but you may want to read http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: im including <?php include_once("check_login_status.php"); ?> at the top of my edit_profile.php when i echo data to input field it display correctly but i cant find the problem in ajax @rm-vanda

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqli_error($db_conx)` to determine what the error is... just have your javascript display it nicely for you.

But also - the variable in your `WHERE` clause ( `$log_username` ) is undefined.

Comment: $log_username is defined in check_login_status.php sir when i echo it i get the logged in username that is logged in

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\Program Files (x86)\VertrigoServ\www\cmstest\edit_profile.php on line 90 and this is what i have on line 90 if(isset($_POST["la"])mysqli_error($db_conx)){

Comment: -- Take the `mysqli_error()` and put it right inside the following `{` -- *then* what does it tell you?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\Program Files (x86)\VertrigoServ\www\cmstest\edit_profile.php on line 104  $firstname = strip_tags(preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['fi'])); is 104

Comment: forgot to put missing semicolon after mysqli_error now i get no error message and database do not update

Comment: My bad, I also meant to tell you that you have to `echo mysqli_error($db_conx);`

Comment: Er, and you're actually also going to want to put that after your `mysqli_query()` - and while you're at it, you may as well put `error_reporting(-1);` at the top